# Exporting smoothened data

Tags: matlab, interpolation, matlab-figure, data-analysis, smoothing

I have a 3d surface and I tried to smoothen it with

```
surf(mydata(1:3752,1:3),'LineStyle', 'none', 'Facecolor', 'interp');   
figure(gcf)
```

I have a smooth surface now with less number of data points missing.

But how do I export this interpolated smooth surface to my workspace??

Comment: You didnt interpolated the surface, you just interpolated teh colour used to plot the surface!

Comment: Ohh, so how to interpolate the data to make my surface smooth??